# "Skip Code Snippet" links

Tags: feature-request, accessibility, code-block

Between [The suggestion that tabular data can be represented well enough using code sections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16356/why-cant-table-markup-elements-be-used), [The suggestion to use ROT13 for "spoilers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text) and the [Web Content Accessibility Guides for ASCII figures](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#ascii-art) I think it would be beneficial to user with disabilities if "Skip This Code Block" hyperlinks were generated around code blocks.

Comment: Low priority. *Really* low.

Comment: I *still* disagree with the tables-as-ascii-art/code issue.

Comment: @David Thomas - Given that most Markdown engines don't offer tables, allowing `<table>` tags would just open the door to a whole new world of invalid markup, so I empathize with the official position on tables, though I disagree with it. I'm actually looking for a way to use the WMD editor with [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) so tables would work, for a different site. [See my SO question on the matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816687/wmd-markdown-editor-with-a-custom-preview)

Comment: yeah, I *understand the *reasons* it'd be a problem, but it's a feature that I think is still, if not **required**, at least a nice-to-have.

Comment: @David Thomas - Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [a_m0d's greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers/7990#7990), which folds code by default.

Comment: That's not the point - in the WAI specs, and generally speaking, it is a good practice to add links (usually invisible to normal users) that allow tools like screenreaders to skip certain page contents, like navigation, or in this case, code blocks.

Comment: @YiJiang: I see, that should indeed be applied then