# Possible to get a mechanism for inserting table information into a question?

Tags: feature-request

Whenever there is a database/sql question people typically like to see some example data.  It can be fairly time consuming to enter meaningful table data into your question.  The typical format looks like:

```
id    |desc    |someFlag
-------------------------
4324  |this    |0 
4325  |is      |0 
4326  |some    |0 
4327  |example |0 
4328  |data    |0
```

Getting this can take a few minutes on it's own but it gets really frustrating when you decide to add another row and have to redo the spacing for every line:

```
id    |desc                                                           |someFlag
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4324  |this                                                           |0 
4325  |is                                                             |0 
4326  |some                                                           |0 
4327  |example                                                        |0 
4328  |data                                                           |0 
4329  |this is a really long description that messes up the formatting|0
```

Would anyone else find it helpful if there was some sort of pop up where you could add columns/rows/data and it would spit out a formatted table to in your question?

Comment: See also [Why can't table markup elements be used?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16356/why-cant-table-markup-elements-be-used) and [is there any markdown to create tables](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables).

Comment: ...and [Easier way to represent DB tables when asking DB questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/easier-way-to-represent-db-tables-when-asking-db-questions)

Comment: +100 for this request (if I could). There are so many questions that are nigh illegible because it is a PITA to draw an ascii table and make it render right in Markdown.