# Ability to add a table in the question for the sample data

Tags: feature-request, markdown

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Possible to get a mechanism for inserting table information into a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82790/possible-to-get-a-mechanism-for-inserting-table-information-into-a-question)
>   [is there any markdown to create tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)
>   [Please add support for tables in answers and questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/please-add-support-for-tables-in-answers-and-questions)

Many questions especially that related with database and SQL contains sample of tabular data like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790310/sql-server-t-sql-get-a-records-set-based-on-a-priority-value-startdate-and-endd):

```
Schedule_____________Start_________________________End

Schedule1____________01/01/2011 00:00______________04/01/2011 00:00
Schedule2____________04/01/2011 00:00______________11/01/2011 14:00
Schedule3____________11/01/2011 14:00______________02/15/2012 00:00
Schedule2____________02/15/2012 00:00______________01/01/2013 00:00
```

I wonder if it's possible to add a table in the question to make inserting data easier and showing it clearer.