# Add a table formatter in the post editor

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add support for tables in answers and questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/please-add-support-for-tables-in-answers-and-questions)

Would be possible to add a new format tool in the post editor?

I'm talking about something that allows the user to simulate a table format. Something like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| AcnttNo | Date1 | Balance1 | Date2  | balance3 | date4 | balance4 |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| 123     | 50282 | 3456     | 45465  | 56557    | 4556  | 324235   |
| 123     | 56757 | 23434    | 234235 | 344324   | 56476 | 5676     |
| 123     | 435   | 2434     | 2343   | 234545   | 24245 | 2423424  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or just

```
AcnttNo   Date1   Balance1   Date2    balance3   date4   balance4  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
123       50282   3456       45465    56557      4556    324235    
123       56757   23434      234235   344324     56476   5676      
123       435     2434       2343     234545     24245   2423424
```

The hardest thing to edit are tables when the indentation isn't correect, and needless to say that it is almost impossible to know what the data of the table is.

A good idea could be that the user clicks on a one of the buttons, and some wizard appears on screen asking for the headers and the data in general.

**Edit:**
The day after I posted this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013044/escape-value-with-urlencode came up with this problem.

[image]

Comment: A great idea, but it seems unlikely. Markdown doesn't have built-in support for tables, so the team would have to write their own code. And no one seems to understand why this is necessary. See also: [is there any markdown to create tables](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables), and [Why can't table markup elements be used?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16356/why-cant-table-markup-elements-be-used).

Comment: @CodyGray I see. I do think it is necessary, mainly in SQL questions, reports, performance tests, etc. `:(`

Comment: At least, the wizard can build/modify ascii tables automatically.

Comment: @jmendeth Or at least let people post their tables in HTML format (using `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`) and automatically convert into an ascii tables :/

Comment: I totally support this. Tables would **rock** !  No fancy formatting needed - plain simple tables would already be a great gain for sketching database tables and so on.